# How to Decode HTML Entity to Local Language (Persian) with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-entities, html-encode

I have encoded HTML entities, and I want to convert them to text.

This is the HTML encoded text:

```
&#1583;&#1575;&#1583;&#1606;
```

And this is decoded text (Persian Language):

دادن

**How can I convert the HTML encoded text to the decoded text using JavaScript?**

Comment: That's HTML (or XML) encoding, not UTF8.

Comment: Those are HTML entities, and not really UTF-8. The values are the same numerically as UTF-8 but that's HTML syntax. UTF-8 can represent *any* language (well, that's the idea anyway).

Comment: `someElement.innerHTML='&#1583;&#1575;&#1583;&#1606;'`

Comment: then what is should do to convert it ?

Comment: Use it as the HTML content of an element and then extract the text, or else parse the entities and construct the string from the character codes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function htmlToText(html) {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = html;
  return el.textContent;
}

var text = htmlToText('&#1583;&#1575;&#1583;&#1606;');
console.log(text);
```

This code takes the HTML entities and converts them into text.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a pure JavaScript solution (no DOM/JQuery) you can do

```js
var decodeHtmlEntities = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(match, dec) {
    return String.fromCharCode(dec);
  });
};

var encodeHtmlEntities = function(str) {
  var buf = [];
  for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    buf.unshift(['&#', str[i].charCodeAt(), ';'].join(''));
  }
  return buf.join('');
};

console.log(decodeHtmlEntities("&#1583;&#1575;&#1583;&#1606;"))
console.log(encodeHtmlEntities("دادن"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var decodedtext = decodeURIComponent('&#1583;&#1575;&#1583;&#1606;');
console.log(decodedtext);
```

Also you can encode with `encodeURIComponent`